# MySQL select and match two tables and update column based on matched data

Tags: mysql, sql, database

It seems difficult for me to thats why I need your help. So basically, I got two tables named `xp_pn_resale` and `xp_guru_properties`. What I need to do is update or set the column `postal_code` from table `xp_pn_resale` based from the data from another table. So here are my tables

My xp_pn_resale table, I wrote query like this in order to show you

```
SELECT postal_code, 
block,
concat(block,' ', street_name) as address 
FROM xp_pn_resale 
where street_name like '%ANG MO KIO%';
```

And I get the result like this

[image]

As you can see, there are `null` values there and there are some `postal_code` that has values because I manually update them based on what I searched. I just want to automatically fill the `postal_code` from the query I got from other table.

Here is my xp_guru_properties table and I wrote query like this in order to show you

```
SELECT property_name as GURU_PROEPRTY_NAME,
property_type as GURU_PROPERTY_TYPE ,
JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(xp_guru_properties.json, '$.postcode') )as GURU_POSTCODE
FROM xp_guru_properties
where property_type like '%HDB%' AND property_name like '%ang mo kio%';
```

And the result is like this

[image]

`xp_guru_properties` got a column `property_type` which is a bit similar in the concatinated columns of `block` and `street_name` from other table I named it as  `GURU_PROPERTY_NAME`.

As you can see, there is the virtual column named `GURU_POSCODE`. The values of that column is what I want to fill in the `postal_code` column from `xp_pn_resale` table. I was doing it manually to update the `postal_code` by doing

```
UPDATE xp_pn_resale 
SET postal_code = 560110 
WHERE street_name LIKE '%ANG MO KIO%' 
AND block = 110
```

which is very tedious to me. Does anyone know how could I automatically update it based on the queries I showed ? Help will be appriciated.

EDIT: I wrote a `JOIN` query like this but this is for the record `Lingkong Tiga` which i manually filled all the `postal_code`

```
select distinct 
JSON_UNQUOTE(json_extract(g.json, '$.postcode')) postcode,
JSON_UNQUOTE(json_extract(g.json, '$.name')) name,
JSON_UNQUOTE(json_extract(g.json, '$.streetnumber') )streetnumber,
p.block, p.street_name, p.postal_code
from xp_pn_resale p
inner join xp_guru_properties g 
    on g.property_name = concat(p.block, ' ', p.street_name)
    where g.property_type like '%HDB%' AND g.property_name like '%Lengkong Tiga%'
```

I got result like this
[image]

Comment: How do you write a `JOIN` query between these two tables?

Comment: What version of MySQL/MariaDB?

Comment: 5.7.22 @TheImpaler

Answer (score 2):

Join the two tables and update.

```
UPDATE xp_pn_resale AS r
JOIN xp_guru_properties AS p ON concat(r.block,' ', r.street_name) = p.property_name
SET r.postal_code = JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(xp_guru_properties.json, '$.postcode') )
WHERE r.street_name like '%ANG MO KIO%'
AND p.property_type like '%HDB%' AND p.property_name like '%ang mo kio%'
AND r.postal_code IS NULL
```

Comment: can you please explain your query line by line sir so that i can use it in other records not just for `ang mo kio` Thanks

Comment: Sir @Barmar, your query seems slow to execute, i tried it in my local until now it is still loading. btw i got 800k data from `xp_pn_resale` and about 30k from `guru`. Can you tell me whats happening?

Comment: I tried executing it but it does nothing in my local phpmyadmin, i think it cancels the query because it is taking too long?

Comment: If the tables are really large, this will be slow because the `LIKE` conditions can't be indexed.

Comment: Okay I see. Do you have any other ideas how could I fix this. I think your query is correct but i dont want to touch it because i know it will work. but it is slow until now its not done loading

Comment: If you put an index on `postal_code` I think it should be able to find the null values quickly. But if there are lots of them it might not help.